# Virtual method 'getApplicationContext()' Failure to display context in application

Tags: android

When displaying a context, a failure occurs. What could be the problem?
No results were found for your request

If results are found, displays if there is no context menu, that no results were found, but it gives an error and application failure

```
 public void run(final View view) throws IOException{
    Log.d(TAG, "run: up and running...");

    if (frag_id==0 || frag_id==1) {  //if home fragment & search fragment
        Log.d(TAG, "getIntentData: frag id not 2");
        if (search_term == null) {
            urlImage = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated";
        } else {
            int randPage;
            do {
                randPage = new Random().nextInt(15);
            }while(randPage==0);
            urlImage = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=" + search_term.toLowerCase() + "&per_page=15&page=" + randPage;
        }
    }

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", StaticUtils.API_KEY)
            .url(urlImage)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {

            final String myResponse = response.body() != null ? response.body().string() : null;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: integrated successfully: ");
                    if (!StaticUtils.imagesListTemp.isEmpty()){
                        StaticUtils.imagesListTemp.clear();
                    }

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);

                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("photos");
                        if (jsonArray.length()>0){
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int imageId = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                                String srcName = jsonObject.getString("photographer");
                                String srcUrl = jsonObject.getString("photographer_url");
                                String dimen = jsonObject.getString("width")+"x"+jsonObject.getString("height");

                                JSONObject srcObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("src");  //getting the image sources of different dimens
                                String imgSrcOrg = srcObject.getString("original");
                                String imgSrcLarg = srcObject.getString("large");
                                String imgSrcMid = srcObject.getString("medium");
                                String imgSrcSml = srcObject.getString("small");
                                String imgSrcPort = srcObject.getString("portrait");
                                String imgSrcLand = srcObject.getString("landscape");
                                String imgSrcTiny = srcObject.getString("tiny");
                                ImageDifferentSize imageArray = new ImageDifferentSize(imgSrcOrg,imgSrcLarg,imgSrcMid,imgSrcSml,imgSrcPort,imgSrcLand,imgSrcTiny);

                                StaticUtils.imagesListTemp.add(new ImagesItem(imageId, srcName, dimen, srcUrl,imageArray));
                                ImagesFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }else{
                            //replace with snackBar
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: List size: "+StaticUtils.imagesListTemp.size());
                        boolean isAddSucceed = StaticUtils.imagesList.addAll(StaticUtils.imagesListTemp);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Copy operation succeed:"+isAddSucceed+", Final arrayList size: "+StaticUtils.imagesList.size());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Json Parsing data error.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

When displaying a context, a failure occurs. What could be the problem?
No results were found for your request

If results are found, displays if there is no context menu, that no results were found, but it gives an error and application failure

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null